# HashMap containsKey returns false for Integer

Tags: java, hashmap, integer, containskey

I have this simple code and i figured out that for the last array number the containsKey method returns always false.

```
int[] indices = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

Map<Integer, Integer> seen = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++) {
    seen.put(indices[i], i);
}
```

All other true except:

```
System.out.println("!!!!! " + seen.containsKey(9) );
```

Also with new

```
int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
```

All other true except:

```
System.out.println("!!!!! " + seen.containsKey(7) );
```

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: You can see the problem for yourself by adding `System.out.println(seen);` -- or just looking at the content of `seen` using a debugger.

Comment: "What is the logic behind this?" - well, what would _you_ say is the logic behind not adding the last element in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't put the last element of your `indices` array in your `Map`.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++) {
    seen.put(indices[i], i);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    seen.put(indices[i], i);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++)
```

change the condition to `i <= indices.length - 1`
or other option is to use `i < indices.length`

In your code, You are adding only upto second last element of the array to the map.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++) {
```

The condition in your for loop is wrong. With **< indices.length -1** you actually only put the first 4 keys into the map. It should be either

```
<= indices.length -1
```

or

```
< indices.length
```

Answer (score 0):

After you populate the map with this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++) {
        seen.put(indices[i], i);
    }
```

it will look like:

```
    {1=0, 3=1, 5=2, 7=3}
```

so you are asking the map if there is a key with the value 9....

the answer is correct, it doesn't have....

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code loop stared from 0 and your last key is  (indices.length -1) .

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not adding the last elements, you loop is running till less then length - 1. Simply either remove -1

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
seen.put(indices[i], i);
}
```

Or use less than equal to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= indices.length - 1; i++) {
seen.put(indices[i], i);
}
```

Its not issue with containsKey , get will  also not give value to you as last element is never added.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents: this is the functional version that avoid these kinds of problems:

```
int[] indices = new int[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

Map<Integer, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, indices.length)
         .mapToObj(i -> {
           return new int[] {i, indices[i]};
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i[1], i -> i[0]));
```